# nose2 can't locate base test script

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose2

I have a test suite for my python app that I run with [nose2](http://nose2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

I used to have all of the tests in a single file; however, that file was getting over 1500 lines long so I've broken it up into multiple separate files.

The suite used to look like this:

```
tests/
    test_all.py
```

And I would run a single test with the following command from just outside the `tests` directory:

```
nose2 tests.test_all.MyTestCase.test_something
```

Now my suite looks something like this:

```
tests/
    base.py
    test_inputs.py
    test_outputs.py
    test_reports.py
```

Testing `base.py` (which simply sets up the test class and has no tests itself) works fine:

```
nose2 tests.base
```

But when I run the following command I get an `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test_output'`:

```
nose2 tests.test_output
```

Further up the traceback I see the following error: `ImportError: No Module named 'base'`. How can I tell `nose2` to use `base.py`?

Comment: how about add `tests/__init__.py`?

Comment: I've tried that...same error

Comment: `nose` by default will load files name starts with `test_`, or none executable, how about change `base.py` to `test_base.py`?